# Emailing CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, sql, excel, email, csv

I have extracted data from my database and displayed it on a webpage in table format. I provided a link on this page which allows the user to download this data as a CSV file. This works correctly so far and when the user follows the link beneath the displayed data it allows them to save it.

It also sends an email with the CSV as an attachment. However currectly the CSV in the attachment is blank and I dont know why.

All i want is for the data from the database which is placed into a downloadable CSV to also go into the attached CSV and I cant do it.

Could someone help me?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
// Create CSV file
fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Branch', 'Website','Company', 'Question1', 'Question2', 'Question3', 'Question4', 'Question5'));

$mysql_connection = db_connect_enhanced('*******','******','******','******');
$query='SELECT * FROM ****.****';
$surveys = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $query);
$count = count($surveys);
$data = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++){
    $data[] = array($surveys[$i]['FeedbackName'], $surveys[$i]['BranchName'], $surveys[$i]['FeedbackWebsite'], $surveys[$i]['FeedbackCompany'], $surveys[$i]['Question1'], $surveys[$i]['Question2'], $surveys[$i]['Question3'], $surveys[$i]['Question4'], $surveys[$i]['Question5']);  
}

foreach( $data as $row )  
{  
    fputcsv($output, $row, ',', '"');  
}  

$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

// create the email and send it off

$subject = "File you requested from RRWH.com";
$from = "***************";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
   boundary="----=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC"' . "\n";

$message = '

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
Content-Type: text/plain;
       charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello

We have attached for you the PHP script that you requested from http://rrwh.com/scripts.php
as a zip file.

Regards

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;  name="';

$message .= "surveys.csv";
$message .= '"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="';
$message .= "surveys.csv";
$message .= '"

';
$message .= "$encoded";
$message .= '

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC--

';
mail("*************", $subject, $message, $headers, "-f$from");
fclose($output);
```

It feels like I am so close but I just cant see the answer :(

Comment: You generate the file `$output`, but I can't see where you're attaching it to the email.

Comment: well the email sends with a CSV attachment. its just that this attachment is empty...excel opens with a blank page

Comment: path issue, gotta be.

Comment: im going to need a little more information. and direction of where to look...examples maybe?

Comment: @user2381872 - Ah, I see. You're generating your CSV file with the fputcsv call, into `$output`. But you're then encoding and attaching `$data` in the `chunk_split` call.

Comment: if your file surveys.csv is on your server in the home folder then the path may be: RRWH.com/public_html/home/surveys.csv

Comment: if you make en echo $encoded....or a var_dump($encoded)....what is it printed on the screen?

Comment: Jim - The serveys.csv file isnt created until the user visits the page. It is then generated and emailed at the same time... @andrewsi - I've changed $data to $output where the $encoded variable is defined but that hasnt made any difference. Still attaches an empty CSV file

Comment: @Robert Rozas - Ok I echo'd out the $encoded variable and all of the data is there

Comment: @user2381872 does your database contain anything once the user submits?

Comment: @user2381872 - have you tried moving `fclose` to just after your foreach loop? You've finished writing the file then, so you can close it.

Comment: the database contains the data in the beginning. What I am doing is taking this data, storing it as a downloadable CSV and also Emailing that CSV to people. the downloadable CSV is fine and contains all the data. But the Emailed one is empty. I have checked the variable which is supposed to populate the CSV file and it is full of the data

Comment: @user2381872 I posted a `suggestive` answer which may be of help.

Comment: @user2381872 Jim mentioned the file's `path`. Have you tried that? For example, you could define `$encoded_file = "/home/public_html/path_to_file/$encoded";` then use `$message .= $encoded_file;` instead of `$message .= $encoded;`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$message .= "$encoded";
```

With this one:

```
$message .= $encoded;
```

Comment: I changed that...but it hasnt made any difference

Answer (score 0):

**This is only a "SUGGESTIVE" answer:**

Here is what I use to attach files and it works for me and it may help you to **"BASE"** yourself with the problem you're having.

```
$file_path = "/path_to_your/$file_name";
$file_path_name = "$file_name"; // this file name will be used at receiver end 

$file = fopen($file_path,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($file_path));
fclose($file); 

$rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$rand}x"; 

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

$message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$message .= "\n\n"; 

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$file_path_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$file_path_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
" filename=\"{$file_path_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data .= "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

Comment: i can get the attachment to go with the email...my problem is the CSV file that is being sent is empty...which just leaves me thinking theres a problem somewhere along the line getting the data into it

Comment: @user2381872 I'm pretty sure you need to define the file path first as shown in my example. Have you used Robert Rozas suggestion as well? I think what's happening is, since there is no content being written, it creates the file anyway and sends it out.